# USB Joystick with C++ and DirectInput

Tags: c++, joystick, directinput

I've been trying to read data (x/y axis, pressed buttons, etc) from a usb joystick, and I've heard of DirectInput. Been searching for some long hours to find a decent example or walkthrough with little success. If anyone can share a simple tutorial, or guide me to the correct place, I'll be in your debt. Thank you

edit: Trying to achieve this goal on Windows platform

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, I'm using Windows7, and hoping the program would work on most of the Windows releases

Comment: [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee418631(v=vs.85).aspx) looks pretty specific to your needs. Not exactly a tutorial, but it is the official site for this stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few DirectInput samples in DirectX SDK, source code and compiled binaries. Included is `Joystick` sample. Older versions of SDK (look for "DirectX 9.0 SDK", years around 2004-2005) had even more samples, up to a dozen!

> Joystick Sample
>
> ---
>
> Description The Joystick sample program obtains and displays joystick
>   data.
>
> Path Source: (SDK root )\Samples\C++\DirectInput\Joystick
>
> Executable: (SDK root )\Samples\C++\DirectInput\Bin\Joystick.exe
>
> User's Guide Observe how the displayed data changes when you move and
>   twist the stick, rotate the throttle wheel, and press buttons in
>   various combinations.
>
> Programming Notes The application polls the joystick for immediate
>   data in response to a timer set inside the dialog procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Probably these might help you:

1. [Directinput devices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb153252%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
2. [Coding4Fun joystick](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16704/Interfacing-with-a-Joystick-using-C)

actually [Coding4Fun](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun) has a lot of interesting things. It began around the time Win7 were released.

Comment: Seems cool, unfortunately the examples are all in C# code. Still useful to get the basic understanding of what is going on, cheers

Answer (score 0):

I used [`walbourn/directx-sdk-samples`](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-samples/tree/master/DirectInput/Joystick) on github and it works perfectly.

I had to configure `.pro` file as follows to run it on Qt Creator:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += c++14
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp
HEADERS += resource.h
DISTFILES += directx.ico joystick.rc
RC_FILE = joystick.rc

DEFINES -= UNICODE
#DEFINES += _MBCS

win32: QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE -= -Zc:strictStrings
win32: QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE -= -Zc:strictStrings
win32: QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_DEBUG -= -Zc:strictStrings
win32: QMAKE_CFLAGS_DEBUG -= -Zc:strictStrings
win32: QMAKE_CFLAGS -= -Zc:strictStrings
win32: QMAKE_CXXFLAGS -= -Zc:strictStrings

LIBS += -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Lib/10.0.10240.0/um/x64"
LIBS += -lshell32 -luser32 -ldxguid -lcomctl32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -ldinput8
```